# Ruby Titleize Simple Form input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

My user gives his university information through simple form as a parameter and sends it to the server.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-s-4 col-sm-4">
  <%= simple_fields_for :users do |r| %>
    <%= r.input :university, required: false, placeholder: "University", label: false %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

How can I titleize the param input the user gives me?

I tried

```
<%= r.input :university.titleize, required: false, placeholder: "University", label: false %>
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter on the input receives the user attribute for which to generate the input, so, it's not the place to chain the `titleize` method.

What you can do is to modify the value sent, before saving the record, or any action you might perform. As an example, if you're sending the data to a create method, then you can modify it after creating the user, and saving it into the database, like:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  @user.university = @user.university.titleize
  ...
```

Comment: Oh ok I didn't know that. I see, so I really have to change it on the server side. I'll try it out.

Comment: Yes, you could add more info to the question on what you're trying to do, still isn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to titleize the text on the client after the user types it, you're going to need to write a javascript handler to manipulate the DOM on some event trigger (maybe on blur?).

On the other hand, if you are trying to titleize the text before you store it in your database, you'll want to do that on the server. Convert the user-inputted text to the titelized version before assigning it the record you're updating.

Answer (score -1):

You can also try this way in your controller:

```
user_params[:university] = user_params[:university].titleize
@user = User.create!(user_params)
```